# How can i improve on this database design

Tags: sql, database

i need to connect these two tables. Basically every text field must have an image , so basically it will be image and then text under that image. I am not sure how i could design this . I have this so far.

**POST table**

post_id

post_title

post_content1 (refers to information that will be under an image about 2 paragraphs long)

post_content2 (refers to information that will be under an image about 2 paragraphs long)

post_content3 (refers to information that will be under an image about 2 paragraphs long)

**images**

post_id (foreign key)

image_1 ( link to post_content1)

image_2 ( link to post_content2)

image_2 ( link to post_content3)

How could i design this?

Comment: Why do you have multiple `post_content` and `image` fields?

Comment: Use the ordinal 1,2,3; `POST_CONTENT [post_id, content_number, content] / POST_IMAGES [post_id, content_number, image]`

Comment: If you find that you're numbering column names in a database design, it's an almost certain sign that you need to normalize those columns into a separate table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, something like this will work better:

**Posts**: post_id, post_title

**Images**: image_id, post_id, image, content

Comment: will this allow me to add specific text under each image coming from database?

Comment: @MillaresRoo what about post content 1, 2 and 3 and 3 images? Can you explain your DB structure a little bit please?

Comment: @LukeSmith Sure.

`image_id = 1, post_id = 1, image ='image_1', content = 'content_for_image_1'
image_id = 2, post_id = 1, image ='image_2', content = 'content_for_image_2'
image_id = 3, post_id = 1, image ='image_3', content = 'content_for_image_3'`

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia With the design that MillaresRoo is presenting, you can have any number of images for a post and they will all have their own text/content. Every image refers to the post it belongs to.